# Solving Nonlinear curve fit to current code

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve-fitting, nonlinear-optimization

I realize that a lot probably has to be added but if someone could point me in the right direction for applying a line of best fit for the exponential graph that would be much appreciated.
Here is what I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []
y = []

readFile = open ('TEXT.txt', 'r')
sepFile = readFile.read().split('\n')
readFile.close()

for plotPair in sepFile:
    xAndY = plotPair.split('\t')
    x.append(int (xAndY[0]))
    y.append(float (xAndY[1]))
print x
print y

plt.plot (x, y, 'o' )
plt.xlabel('')
plt.ylabel('')
plt.show()
```

Comment: To fit a mathematical (e.g. exponential) curve to data, I would use `scipy.stats.expon.fit`. The syntax is the same for any other standard distribution.

Answer (score 2):

In general, truly fitting a non-linear curve is a very difficult problem (mostly because the solution space is infinite and non-continuous), but in general scipy is where you're going to want to look for solutions to this kind of problem. If you know the general form of the equation you can apply a transform to it and use a poly-fit algorithm (still infinite, but continuous) to try fitting it. For that look here:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html

Certainly for an exponential curve this could be used pretty trivially by taking the logarithm of your data.

If you want to really try optimizing some arbitrary least-squares fit you have to stop thinking of curve-fitting and start thinking of multi-variable optimization. Again, scipy is where you should look for solutions to this, but instead check out the optimize library here:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html

Comment: As mentioned, using the logarithm and performing a fit to a straight line is probably best; otherwise, I would go with the `curve_fit` routine from the abovementioned `optimize` package, which seems to be most suited to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using a series of trigonometric functions provided a very robust way for curve fitting. The example below uses a series of `sines` and `cosines`:

```
from scipy import sin, cos, linspace
def f(x, a0,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12,
            c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12):
    return a0 + s1*sin(1*x) +  c1*cos(1*x) \
              + s2*sin(2*x) +  c2*cos(2*x) \
              + s3*sin(3*x) +  c3*cos(3*x) \
              + s4*sin(4*x) +  c4*cos(4*x) \
              + s5*sin(5*x) +  c5*cos(5*x) \
              + s6*sin(6*x) +  c6*cos(6*x) \
              + s7*sin(7*x) +  c7*cos(7*x) \
              + s8*sin(8*x) +  c8*cos(8*x) \
              + s9*sin(9*x) +  c9*cos(9*x) \
             + s10*sin(9*x) + c10*cos(9*x) \
             + s11*sin(9*x) + c11*cos(9*x) \
             + s12*sin(9*x) + c12*cos(9*x)

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y)
x_fit = linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 1000)
y_fit = f(x_fit, *popt)
```

I hope it works for you!